# Devise and Rails 3 redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In my Rails app I use Devise as the authentication system. I have successfully installed the Devide gem and its working fine.

But now I want to redirect user to a different path after they login, ex:

> dash_board#home

How can I define that in Devise? I'm confused as it doesn't have any controllers shows (as sessions, users etc..). I can see them in the gem file, but I guess changing the gem is not a good option

I'm using Rails 3, Devise 1.1.3

Comment: [This link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in) was originally given as an answer, but subsequently deleted for being a link-only answer.